# Reduce GOES Image Collection to get time of first fire detection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, date, reducers, goes-16

I am trying to extract some information from the GOES fire product in Google Earth Engine.

I have written a function that will extract the fire pixels for each image in the collection.

```
// OBTAIN GOES IMAGERY FOR A SINGLE DATE
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC').filterDate('2018-01-04', '2018-01-05');

var GetFirePixels = function(img){
  // SELECT DATA QUALITY FLAGS
  var DQF = img.select('DQF')
  // GET ONLY FIRE PIXELS FROM DQF BAND
  var OnlyFire = DQF.eq(0)
  // RETURN THE FIRE MASK
  return OnlyFire
}

var FirePixels = collection.map(GetFirePixels)
```

I can reduce this new collection to obtain a singular image with all of the fire detections

```
var AllFirePixels = FirePixels.max()
```

However I am not sure how to reduce this new image collection to return the time of first detection as a pixel value? So the output would be similar to "AllFirePixels" but the pixel values would be dates (as a number) instead of 1s

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional layer with the date. Then you `reduce()` your collection with a `ee.Reducer.max()` with `numInputs` set to `2`. That way you get the max fire mask and it's corresponding date. Alternatively, you can use `qualityMosaic()`, providing the fire band name as argument.

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/GOES/16/FDCC').filterDate('2018-01-04', '2018-01-05');

var GetFirePixels = function(img){
  // SELECT DATA QUALITY FLAGS
  var DQF = img.select('DQF')
  // GET ONLY FIRE PIXELS FROM DQF BAND
  var OnlyFire = DQF.eq(0)
  // RETURN THE FIRE MASK
  var fractionalYear = ee.Image(
    img.date().get('year').add(img.date().getFraction('year'))
  ).float().rename('fractionalYear')
  return OnlyFire
    .addBands(fractionalYear)
}

var FirePixels = collection.map(GetFirePixels)
var AllFirePixels = FirePixels.reduce(ee.Reducer.max(2))
  .rename(['fire', 'fractionalYear'])
// var AllFirePixels = FirePixels.qualityMosaic('fire')

Map.addLayer(AllFirePixels, {bands: 'fire'})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2283c14ba61fa1326df7c4d9e0808ae3

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for this comment. I see what you are doing here, but I am trying to understand how you reduced the collection. Does this return the time of the earliest  detected fire at each pixel location?

Comment: I never remember which is be picked up, so I had to check. `max(2)` returns the earliest detected and `qualityMosaic('fire')` the last. https://code.earthengine.google.com/2987b2d31bdb8ad63a9813b5c0db36a3